# JMeter - Reading a Custom Property file in Non-GUI mode

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have a custom property file, which is read via

```
jmeter -q C:/Users/503289283/Downloads/eml_base.properties -t Service_Names.jmx
```

Same thing when executed in Non-GUI mode i.e.

```
jmeter -q C:/Users/503289283/Downloads/eml_base.properties -n -t Service_Names.jmx
```

Throws an undesirable message at the end of run

[image]

Script is running for a longer duration than it should. Output received is perfect.

Solving this could reduce the Test duration (Non-GUI mode).

Thanks for your support.

Regards,
Ajith

Answer (score 0):

The "undesired" message you're getting is from [jsch library](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) which is reading some stream hence JMeter cannot gracefully terminate its threads because SSH connection is open.

So you need to take a look at what is being done on SSH/SFTP level.

I also fail to see any results in the output which means that no samplers have been successfully executed at all, check out [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries. You may also want to [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for the jsch library by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="com.jcraft.jsch" level="debug" />
```